# Refresh Datatable 1.9 without deleting all the rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I'm using dataTables js 1.9

An ajax call to the server get's information from the server that I want to be displayed in the table every 60 seconds or so.

I have no problems implementing solution that clears table and repopulates it:

```
$(id).dataTable().fnClearTable();
for( var i = 0 ; i < json.response.length; i++ ){
    $(id).dataTable().fnAddData([ json.response[i] ]);
}
```

Issue is that the user will get pushed back to page 1 each tome the reload happens since table will be empty momentarily and it will only have 1 page then.

I would like to implement a solution where I first search for rows not in the result, remove those, then add rows that are not in the table. For this I would need to be able to target a row by a value, and I cannot find it in http://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/DataTable.html

Anyone has any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to delete the data and re-populate it, you just need to redraw it.

```
var oTable = $("table").dataTable({ ... your settings ... });

//redraws the table
oTable.fnDraw();
```

Comment: But where do I add the data? I had rows {a,b,c} in the table originally. I get an ajax call with rows {a,b,d}. How would I reflect that using your method?

Comment: If the data is updated in the same dataset, then redrawing the table with the code above, will make another ajax call to refresh the data, and will update the datatable automatically.  Its just like refreshing the page, without refreshing the page. If you need to return a completely different dataset, consider making another datatable.

Comment: How do access the dataset? In the my scenario I just use fnAddData() to append rows to an empty table. I'm not getting how would you add the data to the table, because I don't see the dataset from which to populate the datatable.

Comment: I should mention I'm not using the built-in API. I will look into how that works.

Comment: There are other issues I'm running into as I go, but they are unrelated to this exact issue.

Comment: You need to get into the datatable object, update it's `aoData` property/object that holds all the data in the datatable. If you log the object, you can see all of it's properties and how it's using them. Use `console.log(oTable);` for this.

Comment: I'm getting issues with the pagination, it's in the ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935143/datatables-js-1-9-4-pagination-and-search-doesnt-work-with-server-side-generati

Comment: You might want to post your question on datatables website forums.