# Datatables js 1.9.4 pagination and search doesn't work with server side generation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using datatables js 1.9.4 and use their ajax data population capabilities. When I create them in this way pagination shows controls and search bar is there as well, but neither work. Alos the data table is showing all data in one page.

Here is the generation JS:

```
    $("#prop_table").dataTable({

            "aaSorting": [[2, "desc" ]],
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-9'l><'col-lg-3'f>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-5'i><'col-lg-7'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "<span></span> _INPUT_",
                "sLengthMenu": "<span>_MENU_</span>",
                "oPaginate": { "sFirst": "First", "sLast": "Last" }
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "iDisplayLength":5 ,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/php/api_prop_down.php",
            "aoColumns": [{
                "mData":"name"
              },{
                "mData": "time_down"
              },{
                "mData": "status_id"
              },{
                "mData": "button",
                "mRender": function(data){
                    if (data != "null" )
                        return "<button id=\"prop_issue"+data+"\" issue=\""+data+"\" class=\"btn\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" onclick=\"getTicket("+data+")\">"+data+"</button>";
                    else 
                        return "no ticket";
                }
              }
            ]                      
        });
    $('.dataTables_length select').uniform();
    $('.dataTables_paginate > ul').addClass('pagination');
    $('.dataTables_filter>label>input').addClass('form-control');

    // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
    $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "btn-group",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn",
            "disabled": "btn disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
            "buttons": {
                "normal": "",
                "disabled": "disabled"
            }
        }
    } );

    // Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible dropdown
    $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
            "container": "ul",
            "button": "li",
            "liner": "a"
        }
    } );
```

MY server side script returns a JSON, which is an encoded php array:

```
$output = array("sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $count,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => 5,
    "aaData" => $aaData );

....

echo json_encode(propsDownJSON());
```

Anyone has any insight as to why could this be happening?

Comment: on the server side - you have to use the parameters that are passed and generate what is supposed to be displayed on your table.  If you're only supposed to display 5 - then send only five back to the client

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific? For example is it "iTotalRecords" = 5?

Comment: To my understanding the client should get all of the data in one shot.

Comment: that can work - you would have to make an ajax call on page load - then not use server side processing.  If you want to use server side processing you will have to check the parameters sent to the server - process them and build the results - then send back to the client the data to be displayed - It sounds like you want to make one call and process the data on the client side

Comment: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side - this tells you what each parameter means

Comment: example of PHP server side proecessing https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql